# Leaflet: Fading in/out layer groups efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, leaflet

I've got a Leaflet map with a single tile layer and then a `LayerGroup` (`densityLayer`) consisting of many (typically a few hundred) `Rectangle` layers, each of which is a semitransparent filled overlay with its fillColor based on population density for a particular year.

Based on a user action, the contents of `densityLayer` change. Pretty trivial to just run `densityLayer.clearLayers()` then generate all the new `Rectangle` layers and `densityLayer.addLayer(aRectangle)` for each of them.

What I *want* to do, though, is to animate a fade from the old to the new data: i.e., generate all the new `Rectangle` layers and put them in a new `LayerGroup` (`newDensityLayer`), and simultaneously fade out the original `oldDensityLayer` and fade in the `newDensityLayer`, and when the fade is complete, then clear out and remove `oldDensityLayer` and replace it with `newDensityLayer`.

My current solution is hideously inefficient:

```
var oldDensityLayer = densityLayer
var newDensityLayer = {...create new density layer here, add polygons, etc...}

oldDensityLayer.eachLayer(function(l) {
  $(l._path).fadeOut(1000) // 1000ms animation time
})

setTimeout(function() {
  oldDensityLayer.clearLayers()
  myLeafletMap.removeLayer(oldDensityLayer)
  oldDensityLayer = null
}, 1000)

myLeafletMap.addLayer(newDensityLayer)

// now fade in all the new polygons
newDensityLayer.eachLayer(function(l) {
  $(l._path).hide() // so they start out invisible
  $(l._path).fadeIn(1000)
})

densityLayer = newDensityLayer
```

This basically works, but gets pretty choppy and slow on anything but a very fast machine.

Is there some way to fade in/out an entire `LayerGroup`, or perhaps some option I haven't considered...?

This is critical functionality, so if adding another js library would help, that's fine. Also, SVG-specific answers are fine, as that's what I've got Leaflet using for its drawing functions, and cross-browser compatibility isn't a concern in this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some way to fade in/out an entire `LayerGroup`, or perhaps some option I haven't considered...?

There is, in fact, an option which you haven't considered: manipulate the [`L.Renderer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#renderer) which actually draws the geometries as an HTML element. This means manipulating the actual `<canvas>` of a `L.Canvas`, or the actual `<svg>` of a `L.SVG`.

Remember any subclass of `L.Path` (`Polygon`s, `Polyline`s and such) can have [its own renderer](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#renderer). Leaflet, by default, creates just one instance of `L.Renderer` and reuses it in all `L.Path`s unless told otherwise - this means less HTML elements and (in 99% of use cases) better performance.

So it should look something like:

```
var rendererA = L.canvas();
var rendererB = L.canvas();

var groupA = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerA1 = L.polygon(…, {renderer: rendererA}).addTo(groupA);
var layerA2 = L.polygon(…, {renderer: rendererA}).addTo(groupA);

var groupB = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerB1 = L.polygon(…, {renderer: rendererB}).addTo(groupB);
var layerB2 = L.polygon(…, {renderer: rendererB}).addTo(groupB);

// Here comes the magic - using the *undocumented*, *private* _container
// property of L.Canvas to access the <canvas> HTML element itself
rendererA._container.style.opacity = 0.5;
```

The code is obviously incomplete, but it should illustrate the idea properly.

That will create two different `<canvas>` in the browser, and changing the opacity of the HTML element itself will bypass re-rendering the features. There should be an analogous solution using `L.SVG` instead, but I'm not sure how browsers composite the opacity of SVG containers.

There are obvious disadvantages for this method - like losing any z-ordering (`bringToFront`, etc) if geometries from both groups should be intertwined.

Also, please remember: **Using undocumented, private properties of leaflet objects is not recommended unless you really really really know what you're doing** and are willing to see your code break in API changes or rare circumstances.

Comment: This looks very promising. Going to test it out today.

Comment: Ah - this is Leaflet 1.0 functionality. Given that it might solve my problem, I'm going to give upgrading to 1.0RC1 a try.

Comment: This worked quite well; I created three renderers ("a","b" and "c") and cycled through them, fading one in while one faded out, and keeping the third as a "stale" layer so I didn't run into any race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You could include an SVG layer populated with your shapes. Below in an example that fades out 500 svg shapes, then builds a new bunch of SVG shapes and fades them in. (Edited to zoom shapes at their locations)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Fade Out/In SVG Elements in Leaflet World Map</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.5/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

</head>

<body style='font-family:arial'>
<center><h4>Fade Out/In SVG Elements in Leaflet World Map</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
This adds 500 svg elements(circles, ellipses, rects, polygons) to the SVG layer in the world map. The map's mouse wheel zoom remains smooth in IE/CH/FF. Each element has a lat/lng value, converted to the needed x,y values to translate each symbol to the desired point.
During map zoom level changes, the symbols are automatically scaled and translated, maintaining their original size and position.

</div>
<br />
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>
<b>Scenerio:</b><br />
1). The map is placed into its DIV (width:800px, height:400px).<br />
2). The map is centered at Lat/Lng (0,0) at zoom level 1.<br />
3.) The SVG element is added via <b>initPathRoot.</b><br />
4.) 500 SVG elements are added, randomly place about the world.<br />
5.) The svg <b>viewBox</b> is computed, used to create x,y values for the symbols.<br />
6.)Each element is translated/scaled when the map is zoomed, using the <b>viewreset</b> event.<br /> This calls the map method <b>latLngToLayerPoint(MyLatLng)</b> to accomplish this.
 <br>7.) Select <button>fade out/in</button> to fade out the current elements, build a new group, then fade In new group
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div  style='width:800px;height:400px' id='MyMap'></div>
  <button onClick=fadeOutIn()>fade out/in</button>

  <br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea spellcheck=false id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>

<script id=myScript>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmhlbXNoZXIiLCJhIjoiODQ5MW9WayJ9.px2P6wVMFucfXHE1zmDA1A';
MyMap = L.mapbox.map('MyMap', 'mapbox.streets', { zoomControl:false,center: new L.latLng(0,0),zoom:1,minZoom:1});
//---zooming the map---
MyMap.on("viewreset", adjustSVGSymbols);

var MySVG
var SymbolG //---<g> element containing all symbols---
var VBw
var VBh
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

//---body onload---
function initSVG()
{
 MyMap._initPathRoot() //---creates an svg layer---
 MySVG=document.querySelector("svg") //---access svg element---
 //---place symbols in here---
 SymbolG=document.createElementNS(NS,"g")
    SymbolG.setAttribute("id","symbolG")
 MySVG.appendChild(SymbolG)
 //---create random svg elements, place in SymbolG--
 getViewBox()//---used to place svg random elements
 //---create 500 symbols at size 10 pixels--
 svgGLOB(500,10)
}

//--- on map zoom - fired via map event: viewreset---
function adjustSVGSymbols()
{

 var symbols=SymbolG.childNodes
 for(var k=0;k<symbols.length;k++)
 {
  var symbol=symbols.item(k)
  //---initial lat/lng for symbol---
  var lat=parseFloat(symbol.getAttribute("lat"))
  var lng=parseFloat(symbol.getAttribute("lng"))
  var latLng= new  L.latLng(lat, lng)
  var transX=MyMap.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).x
  var transY=MyMap.latLngToLayerPoint(latLng).y
           //---scale---
                var initZoom=parseFloat(symbol.getAttribute("initZoom"))
                var scale = (Math.pow(2, MyMap.getZoom())/2)/(Math.pow(2, initZoom)/2);
   //---trash previous transform---
  symbol.setAttribute("transform","")
  symbol.removeAttribute("transform")

  var transformRequestObj=MySVG.createSVGTransform()
  var animTransformList=symbol.transform
  //---get baseVal to access/place object transforms
  var transformList=animTransformList.baseVal
  //---translate----
  transformRequestObj.setTranslate(transX,transY)
  transformList.appendItem(transformRequestObj)
  transformList.consolidate()
  //---scale---
  transformRequestObj.setScale(scale,scale)
  transformList.appendItem(transformRequestObj)
  transformList.consolidate()
 }


}
//---needed for random symbol placement: create x,y values---
function getViewBox()
{
 vb=MySVG.viewBox.baseVal
 VBw=vb.width
 VBh=vb.height
}
//---compute svg elems: circles, rects, ellipses, polygons---
function svgGLOB(elems,elemSize)
{
 //---note: each browser creates a different sized svg layer---
 var svgWidth=VBw
 var svgHeight=VBh
 //---obtain a random whole number from a thru b---
 function rdm(a,b)
 {
  return a + Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1));
 }

 function randomPoints(elems,svgWidth,svgHeight,elemSize)
 {
  //--return format:[ [x,y],[x,y],,, ]
  //---Generate  random points---
  function times(n, fn)
  {
   var a = [], i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
    a.push(fn(i));
   }
   return a;
  }
  var width=svgWidth-2*elemSize //---offset from edge---
  var height=svgHeight-2*elemSize //---offset from edge---

  return  RandomPnts = times(elems, function() { return [Math.floor(width * Math.random()) + elemSize, Math.floor(height * Math.random()) + elemSize] });
 }
 //---random color---
 function rcolor()
 {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
  {
   color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
 }
 function polygon(vCnt,radius,centerX,centerY)
 {
  var myPoints=[]
  var polyXPts      = Array(vCnt);
  var polyYPts      = Array(vCnt);
  var vertexAngle   = 360/vCnt;
  //---init polygon points processor---
  for(var v=0; v<vCnt; v++)
  {
   theAngle = (v*vertexAngle)*Math.PI/180;
   polyXPts[v] = radius*Math.cos(theAngle);
   polyYPts[v] = -radius*Math.sin(theAngle);
  }
  //--note points are CCW---
  for(var v=0;v<vCnt; v++)
  {
   var point=[centerX+polyXPts[v],centerY+polyYPts[v]]
   myPoints.push(point)
  }
  return myPoints
 }

 var Points=randomPoints(elems,svgWidth,svgHeight,elemSize)

 var n=Points.length
 var circleCnt=0
 var ellipseCnt=0
 var rectCnt=0
 var polygonCnt=0

 var RandomElems=[]
 RandomElems[0]="circle"
 RandomElems[1]="rect"
 RandomElems[2]="ellipse"
 RandomElems[3]="polygon_3"
 RandomElems[4]="polygon_4"
 RandomElems[5]="polygon_5"
 RandomElems[6]="polygon_6"
 RandomElems[7]="polygon_7"
 RandomElems[8]="polygon_8"
 RandomElems[9]="polygon_9"
 RandomElems[10]="polygon_10"
 RandomElems[11]="polygon_11"
 RandomElems[12]="polygon_12"

 //---create all at center(0,0), then translate---

 for(var k=0;k<n;k++)
 {
  var rand=rdm(0,12)
  var elemStr=RandomElems[rand]

  if(!elemStr.indexOf("_"))
  var elemSt=elemStr
  else
  var elemSt=elemStr.split("_")[0]

  //var elem=document.createElementNS(NS,elemSt)
  var x=Points[k][0]
  var y=Points[k][1]

  var lng=((x * 360 / VBw) - 180)
  var lat= (90 - (y * 180 / VBh))

  var id="symbol"+k

  var fill=rcolor()
  var elem=document.createElementNS(NS,elemSt)
  elem.setAttribute("id",id)
  elem.setAttribute("cursor","default")
  elem.setAttribute("fill",fill)
  elem.setAttribute("lat",lat)
  elem.setAttribute("lng",lng)

  if(elemSt=="circle")
  {
   var r=elemSize
   elem.setAttribute("r",r)
  }
  else if(elemSt=="ellipse")
  {
   var rx=elemSize
   var ry=elemSize/2
   elem.setAttribute("rx",rx)
   elem.setAttribute("ry",ry)
  }
  else if(elemSt=="rect")
  {
   var width=elemSize
   var height=elemSize
   //---center at 0,0---
   var x=-elemSize/2
   var y=-elemSize/2

   elem.setAttribute("width",width)
   elem.setAttribute("height",height)
   elem.setAttribute("x",x)
   elem.setAttribute("y",y)
  }
  else if(elemSt=="polygon")
  {
   var pgonSides=parseInt(elemStr.split("_")[1])
   var pgonPnts=polygon(pgonSides,elemSize,0,0)

   var points=pgonPnts.join()
   elem.setAttribute("points",points)
  }

        elem.setAttribute("initZoom",1)

  SymbolG.appendChild(elem)
 }
 //---initialize locations---
 adjustSVGSymbols()
 }
//---fade out/In button----
function fadeOutIn()
{
    $("#symbolG").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            createAnotherGlob()
        });
}
function createAnotherGlob()
{
    var symbols=SymbolG.childNodes
    for(var k=symbols.length-1;k>=0;k--)
    SymbolG.removeChild(symbols.item(k))

    svgGLOB(500,10,true)

     $("#symbolG").fadeIn(1500)

}

</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
 jsValue.value=myScript.text
 initSVG()
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```